# Aptana not copying files to external server

Tags: html, testing, localhost, aptana, external

I just set up Aptana and have configured the Apache testing server in the folder C:\Apache\htdocs. When I try to test a simple HTML file I am directed to localhost/myproject/myfile.html but I get a 404 error. Upon inspecting the folder I find it empty. If I put a file in that folder the external server displays it just fine, but Aptana is not loading the files on the testing server when I attempt to run them. Any ideas? I know it's something simple, but I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the best solution to this problem. I discovered I needed to install an FTP server on the local machine. I installed and configured Filezilla server and voila - problem solved. The only tip I'd add is to make sure to set the permissions properly for the folder or you'll run into errors.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I discovered for this seems like a workaround but may be the only way to perform the task. I simply set up the localhost server just as if I was publishing the site to a remote location. Of course, the files don't update automatically when viewed like Dreamweaver does, but it works.

Comment: How did you set up localhost as an external server? It seems I need a username and password for localhost but can't figure out what these should be.